# Video not growing in height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wistia

After transferring my website site from one domain to the other, my NEW **about us page** for some reason is shrinking my video. 
From my findings the div which is holding the iframe seems not to be growing more that 181px. If it grows, then the video will automatically re-adjusts itself and grow. This is working perfectly on the old link

Can someone please check this for me to see what is causing the second link not to work correctly like the first. The video is located at the top and is the MAIN video.

Link with **GOOD VIDEO** : http://rossiterandco-2.hs-sites.com/about-us

Link with **BAD VIDEO**: http://rossiterandco-1.hs-sites.com/about

Comment: Have you compared the HTML output line by line? http://www.diffnow.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the rules of the stylesheet have changed. You need to add back/modify the following rules to hubtheme-style.min.css:

```
.hs-responsive-embed iframe, .hs-responsive-embed object, .hs-responsive-embed embed {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}
.hs-responsive-embed, .hs-responsive-embed.hs-responsive-embed-youtube, .hs-responsive-embed.hs-responsive-embed-wistia, .hs-responsive-embed.hs-responsive-embed-vimeo {
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
}
```

The best way to find these problems in the future is by beautifying the stylesheets and using a diff tool. I recommend using [difftool.net](http://www.difftool.net/) since it only shows identical text that's near changes (not the rest of an enormous file).